# MySQL to get the count of rows that fall on a date for each day of a month

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table that contains a list of community events with columns for the days the event starts and ends.  If the end date is 0 then the event occurs only on the start day.  I have a query that returns the number of events happening on any given day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM p_community e WHERE 
    (TO_DAYS(e.date_ends)=0 AND DATE(e.date_starts)=DATE('2009-05-13')) OR
    (DATE('2009-05-13')>=DATE(e.date_starts) AND DATE('2009-05-13')<=DATE(e.date_ends))
```

I just sub in any date I want to test for "2009-05-13".

I need to be be able to fetch this data for every day in an entire month.  I could just run the query against each day one at a time, but I'd rather run one query that can give me the entire month at once.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might do that?

And no, I can't use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(date) FROM table WHERE DATE(dtCreatedAt) >= DATE('2009-03-01') AND DATE(dtCreatedAt) <= DATE('2009-03-10') GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

This would get the amount for each day in may 2009.

UPDATED: Now works on a range of dates spanning months/years.

Comment: I would add a few columns to the select, but yea this should do it.

Comment: That's all he put in the example so I went with that.

Comment: This would work if each event were a single date, but I'm dealing with a date range on each item.  Each event spans from date_starts to date_ends, so if an event is May 10th to May 14th, I need to be able to recognize May 12th.

Comment: I think I might be confused by your explanation of the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I think you got it backwards.  Quassnoi seems to get what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, `MySQL` lacks a way to generate a rowset of given number of rows.

You can create a helper table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_day (day INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT
INTO    t_day (day)
VALUES  (1),
        (2),
        …,
        (31)
```

and use it in a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  day, COUNT(*)
FROM    t_day
JOIN    p_community e
ON      day BETWEEN DATE(e.start) AND IF(DATE(e.end), DATE(e.end), DATE(e.start))
GROUP BY
        day
```

Or you may use an ugly subquery:

```
SELECT  day, COUNT(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS day
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS day
        …
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  31 AS day
        ) t_day
JOIN    p_community e
ON      day BETWEEN DATE(e.start) AND IF(DATE(e.end), DATE(e.end), DATE(e.start))
GROUP BY
        day
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I expected to do.  I didn't know about the BETWEEN keyword tho, that's a lot nicer than what I came up with.